# Getting the current locale's charset in C?

Tags: c, locale

How can I find the current locale's charset in C?

setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) returns "en_US.UTF8", but is there a way to get the charset? In /etc/locale.gen on my system it lists the locales and the charsets, so it's not in the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query various parameters of the current locale using the [`nl_langinfo`(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nl_langinfo) function. The charset is obtained by calling `nl_langinfo(CODESET)`.

Note, that you have to call `setlocale` before using `nl_langinfo` to make your program locale-aware.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do this on Windows?

Comment: @Jookia: I'd say just define UNICODE and use the `wchar_t` APIs for everything in Windows. Quick search in MSDN suggests looking for `_getmbcp` function to get the encoding (note, that windows uses the numerical codes of the encodings), but use that just for interpreting legacy text files.

Comment: The wchar_t APIs are UTF-16, so is it safe to assume I should just throw UTF-16 text at Windows?

Comment: @Jookia: Yes, throw utf-16 text at Windows. I don't think windows actually understand utf-16, just ucs-2, i.e. do not do anything with surrogate pairs, but I don't think they really need to and I don't think they choke on them.